# Right way to call a model within a view in Backbone (not using RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, sprockets

### The goal

Call `UserModel` within `AuthenticationView` with Backbone + Sprockets.

### The problem

I just don't know a good way to do that.

### The scenario

This is my view (`assets/js/views/AuthenticationView.js`):

```
var AuthenticationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.authentication-form'),
    events: {
        'keyup input[name=email]'       : 'validationScope',
        'keyup input[name=password]'    : 'validationScope',
        'submit form[data-remote=true]' : 'authenticate'
    },
    render: function() {
    },
    authenticate: function() {
        // Here I'm going interact with the model. 
    }
});
```

And that's my model (`assets/js/models/UserModel.js`):

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/sessions'
});
```

### The question

How can I make the interaction between the view and the model?

*Remember: they're in separated files.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the constructors together would be step 1 -- separate files don't matter, you can use Browserify/requirejs or just throw these things in global scope. From there, since passing an object into a view constructor with the property name 'model', automatically assigns the value to the view's `this.model`. So if we have an `initialize` method in our view, we can see:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  console.log(this.model); // User instance
  this.model.on('update', function () {});
}
```

And so we can pass in an instantiated model into the view via an object's `model` property:

```
var model = new UserModel(); 
var view = new AuthenticationView({ model: model });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/ here is great article about js modules lazy loading  with examples used backbonejs and requirejs